# How do I include new gems that are automatically there whenever I create a new rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, rubygems

Usually, I paste the gem code in the gem file and bundle install. But I realised I have multiple gems I use over and over. How do I include those gems automatically whenever I create a new rails app?

Any help appreciated. I'm still new. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have a starter template for new rails apps that I use.  Basically has my testing gems ect. and certain folders that I like created in each.  Basically rather than rails newing I will just clone the starter repo.

Comment: Thank you. how do I clone it?

Comment: Assuming you are using github: https://help.github.com/articles/cloning-a-repository/

Comment: I don't have GitHub is there another way to do it?

Comment: You only need git to clone a github repository. You don't need any GitHub account if the repository is public.

Comment: You don't have to use github but I would strongly advise you use git(not just for this but in general).  Bitbucket is a good if you need a private repo.

Answer (score 0):

I think he might be referring to just having an initial app that you can clone yourself like `copy+paste`

It's a nice idea, but I don't know an automated solution to this.